# How to properly override ArrayList .remove() method

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to override add() and remove() methods from my ArrayList of clients.

If I add or delete a client, the sum of the orders of the clients that are on the list must be automatically updated.

Actually I have something like this:

```
public class Path {
  private ArrayList<Client> clients = new ArrayList<Client>() {
    @Override
    public boolean add(Client e) {
      boolean allOk = super.add(e);
      if (allOk)
        calcTotalOrder();
      return allOk;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean remove(Client e) {
      boolean allOk = super.remove(e);
      if (allOk)
        calcTotalOrder();
      return allOk;
    }
  };
}
```

I have no problem when overriding add() method and it actually works exactly as I want, but not the same luck with remove().

I get the following error: "The method remove(Client) of type new ArrayList(){} must override or implement a supertype method".

The proposal of Eclipse is to eliminate @Override

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `remove` doesn't use generics and takes an `Object` parameter, the method's signature is `public boolean remove(Object obj)` .

Comment: The error is because  `ArrayList::remove` takes an `Object`. That said, you probably don't want to subclass `ArrayList`; you probably want to delegate to it instead and have the code that does `calcTotalOrder` live in the method that's doing the delegating.

Comment: @PM77-1 - it looks like there's a code block from the ArrayList declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
public boolean remove(Client e)
```

by

```
public boolean remove(Object e)
```

Answer (score 1):

For historical reasons, the `remove()` method is not polymorphic, i.e. it must support removing an arbitrary `Object` and not an object of type `T`.

However, you have to remember to also override the respective iterator methods (since calling `remove()` is not the only way to add things into an `ArrayList`), as well as all the other methods that modify elements in the collection (i.e. `set()`).

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at `java.util.ArrayList`, it has two remove methods:

```
public boolean remove(Object o)

public boolean remove(int index)
```

You need to override these methods. Also, list iterators can remove elements as well, if you need full removal support, you have to override the list iterator.

Comment: remove(int index) actually returns the object that was removed, not a boolean

Answer (score 0):

**When overriding methods, the signatures must be the same**. Otherwise, you're not overriding. You can simply go to the `List` implementation and look at the methods you're attempting to override. In your case, it's `remove` and `add`. You will find that the method signature does not take your `Client` object as a parameter. Instead, it takes `Object` as a parameter.

In order to override, you must maintain the methods signature. `Object` is the super class to all java objects, and the error "must override or implement a supertype method" is simply telling you that you're using the `@Override` annotation, without actually overriding anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can change that remove to Object and it will work because remove takes an object. You will have a problem though if someone uses a different way to add object. Like addAll() or creating an ArrayList from a collection constructor.

In order to use that instead of modifying ArrayList methods you can extend the ArrayList to be like "ArrayList that can calculate order". Something like:

```
class ArrayListThatCalculatesTotalOrder extends ArrayList<Client>{
     .... your private calcTotalOrder() methods is here ....
    public TotalOrder getTotalOrder(){
        calcTotalOrder();
        return totalOrder;
    }
}
```

This way you will be able to use it as a list freely but you can also get the calculated total order with a simple getter in a standard way. Or something similar to that depending on what exactly do you need. It is better to add behavior than to modify the existing one.